# How to load & use a WEKA model in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, weka, prediction

I'm writing a rails app that helps the user to predict sentiment analysis in text.

After using the WEKA GUI, I have an output of the model file.

I would like to know how to **load** the **WEKA model** file in *Ruby*, and evaluate prediction on a specific data (*string*).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Guess there is no good answer except for using jruby?